# unable to connect to Database:l

Tags: java, mysql

Please find my code below, I am unable to connect to Database: Error is displayed in the line   `Statement s=c.createStatement();`. The error is:

> Cannot convert java.sql.statement to com.mysql.dbc.statement"

```
 String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
 String url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/student_db";
 String uname="root";
 String pass="admin";
 Class.forName(driver);
 Connection c=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,uname,pass);
 Statement s=c.createStatement(); 
 s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `student_db`.`studentinfo` (`Student_ID`, `Student_FirstName`, `Student_LastName`, `Student_EmailID`,`Student_course`) VALUES ('9'+'"+firstname+"','"+lastname+"','"+emailaddress+"','"+Course+"')");
```

Comment: Show us your `import`s (and use java.sql.Statement)

Comment: You might also want to read on [sql injection](http://xkcd.com/327/). Think about a  student named is "L'Homme"

Answer (score 0):

Use interface :

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
```

Remove

```
import com.mysql.dbc.statement
```

etc...

Comment: These have been added before, the error is in  Statement s=c.createStatement();